# How to set tmux socket name dependening on tmux version?

Tags: linux, tmux

I have a system without root access. To install my own packages, I use sometimes nix-env or junest or some other custom user-namespace/proot mechanisms. That means I have different versions of tmux installed, and all of them try to communicate via /tmp/tmux-$UID/default= socket. Because of version and root differences, the communication very much fails.

Is there something I could set in .tmux.conf that would make the socket file versioned using the tmux version? Like `tmux -S "default-$(tmux -V)"`?

Comment: A wrapper that uses `tmux -V` to set `TMUX_TMPDIR` or to create an option-argument for `-S` or `-L` may work. You asked for "something I could set in `.tmux.conf`"; a wrapper needs to be set up beyond `.tmux.conf`, therefore it's not an answer.